# Group generated by commuting elements of PSL(2, $\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

I read a question that says given $f,g \in PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$, such that $f \circ g = g \circ f$, show $g(Fix(f)) = Fix(f)$ where $Fix(f) = \{x \in \mathbb{H} \cup \partial \mathbb{H}| f(x) =x\}$. Then we are asked to show that $\Gamma = \langle f,g \rangle$ is not Fuchsian. I believe this is not well-posed since Abelian Fuchsian groups exist, I believe. Am I correct?

Comment: This is rather vague. You have stated no conditions on $f,g$ whatsoever. Certainly one can write down examples of $f,g$ such that $\Gamma$ is not Fuchsian, leading to wonder whether that question you read has a little more to it.

Comment: We have that $f,g \in PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ such that $f \circ g = g \circ f$. We also have that $g(Fix(f)) = Fix(f)$ where $Fix(f) = \{x \in \mathbb{H} \cup \partial \mathbb{H}| f(x) =x\}$

Comment: What is the source of your question? Is "Fuchsian group" defined in that source, or are you left to your own devices to look the definition up?

Comment: A subgroup $\Gamma < PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is Fuchsian if it is a discrete subset of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 3):

If $f,g$ are commuting elements of $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ then the group $\langle f,g\rangle$ they generate may or may not be discrete, and hence using the definition in your comment that group may or may not be Fuchsian. So if Fuchsian is defined in your source as you say it is, then you are correct, the problem is not well-posed.

For example, if $f = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $g = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \sqrt{2} \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ then  $\langle f,g\rangle$ is not discrete hence not Fuchsian.

For another example, if $f = g = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ then $\langle f,g\rangle$ is discrete, hence Fuchsian.

Or, to make it more interesting, if $f = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $g = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, then $\langle f,g\rangle$ is discrete, hence Fuchsian.

The reason that I pressed you in the comments regarding how Fuchsian was defined in the source that you were consulting is that every abelian subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ is an [elementary group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleinian_group#Elementary_and_reducible_Kleinian_groups) (meaning one whose limit set in $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is $0$, $1$ or $2$ points), and I believe that there may be some older sources where elementary subgroups are disallowed in the definition of Fuchsian. But I don't think that is standard usage now (if it ever was). Nowadays people are perfectly happy to speak about elementary Fuchsian groups.

Comment: So how would one go about showing that $\langle f,g\rangle$ is not Fuchsian?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking for more details why the two elements I gave in my answer generate a non-discrete group?

Comment: I am trying to solve the question as it was posed: to show that $\langle f,g\rangle$ is not Fuchsian. My thinking is that because $f,g$ have the same fixed points they must be maps of the same type so taking iterates and then taking $(f^n)^{-1} \circ g^n$ gives us something converging to the identity and so the identity is not isolated and the group is not Fuchsian

Comment: What my answer shows is this: **If** Fuchsian is defined in your source as you say it is, then you are correct, the problem is not well posed. For some examples $\langle f,g\rangle$ is indiscrete and hence not Fuchsian (I gave one explicitly), and for other examples $\langle f,g \rangle$ is discrete and hence Fuchsian.

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify these points.